# search two dataframes for when variables meet at samerow

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

**I am iterating through a directory of files (.pdf files) that are names '`FIRST LAST Zip.pdf`'... I save the name and zip into variables just fine.. Then I basically want to get the row number they match at (via excel in pandas), then with the row number, get that row's column value as the new name i.e. `ID`.**

I have the below; which worked for about 1/6 if my files. The rest are just hitting the prints 'no match found', when there is indefinite matches found. No errors in terminal, just remaining files (ALOT) which definite matches, just output 'match not found, match not found'. Is it something with `index.min()`?

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

import re
import config
import xlrd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import os

for filename in os.listdir(config.Total):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        First_Name, Last_Name, Zip = filename.replace(".pdf",'').split()
        Name = First_Name + " " + Last_Name

        print(Name)
        print(Zip)
        data1 = pd.read_excel(config.Excel1)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
        header = df.iloc[0]

        df = df[1:]
        df.rename(columns = header)

        row_numberd1 = df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(Name)].index.min()
        row_numberd12 = df[df['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)].index.min()

        if row_numberd1 == row_numberd12: # When rows match of NameUp and Zip var in DF1
            rowMatched = row_numberd1
            print("Match Found in DF1")
            print(rowMatched)

            MemberID = df['ID'][rowMatched]
            MemberI = str(MemberID)

            os.rename(config.Total+filename, config.ID+MemberI+'.pdf')

        else:
            print("No Match Found in DF1, Search Df2")

            data2 = pd.read_excel(config.Excel2)

            df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
            header2 = df2.iloc[0]

            df2 = df2[1:]
            df2.rename(columns = header2)

            row_numberd2 = df2[df2['Member Name'].str.contains(Name)].index.min()
            row_numberd22 = df2[df2['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)].index.min()

            if row_numberd2 == row_numberd22: # When rows match of NameUp and Zip var in DF2
                rowMatched2 = row_numberd2
                print("Match Found in DF2")
                print(rowMatched2)

                MemberID = df2['ID'][rowMatched2]
                MemberI = str(MemberID)

                os.rename(config.Total+filename, config.ID+MemberI+'.pdf')
```

**Update; via the comment I am trying this!**

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

import re
import config
import xlrd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import os

data1 = pd.read_excel(config.Excel1)
data2 = pd.read_excel(config.Excel2)

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
header = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.rename(columns = header)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
header2 = df2.iloc[0]
df2 = df2[1:]
df2.rename(columns = header2)

for filename in os.listdir(config.Total):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        First_Name, Last_Name, Zip = filename.replace(".pdf",'').split()
        Name = First_Name + " " + Last_Name

        print(Name)
        print(Zip)

        UniqueMatch = len(df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(Name) & df['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)]) == 1

        if UniqueMatch: # When rows match of NameUp and Zip var in DF1
            rowMatched = UniqueMatch
            print("Match Found in DF1")
            print(rowMatched)

            MemberID = df['ID'][rowMatched]
            MemberI = str(MemberID)

            os.rename(config.Total+filename, config.ID+MemberI+'.pdf')
        else:
            print("Match not Found in DF1")
            print("No Match Found in DF1, Search Df2")

            UniqueMatch2 = len(df2[df2['Member Name'].str.contains(Name) & df2['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)]) == 1

            if UniqueMatch2: # When rows match of NameUp and Zip var in DF2
                rowMatched2 = UniqueMatch2
                print("Match Found in DF2")
                print(rowMatched2)

                MemberID = df2['ID'][rowMatched2]
                MemberI = str(MemberID)

                os.rename(config.Total+filename, config.ID+MemberI+'.pdf')
            else: 
                print("Match not Found in DF2")
```

*But it is outputting an error and failing when I try to rename with the row number `ID` column value:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rename.py", line 60, in <module>
    MemberID = df2['ID'][rowMatched2]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1064, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4723, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
```

---

**Final Update:** It's still only catching some of the matches below, via `@ilfy6` comments/suggestions.

```
for filename in os.listdir(config.Total2):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        First_Name, Last_Name, Zip = filename.replace(".pdf",'').split()
        Name = First_Name + " " + Last_Name

        print(Name)
        print(Zip)

        matches2 = df2[df['Member Name'].str.contains(Name) & df2['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)]

        if len(matches2) == 1:
            row_index = matches2.iloc[0]['ID']
            print("Match Found in DF2")
            print(row_index)

            # MemberID = df2.loc[row_index, 'ID']
            MemberI = str(row_index)

            os.rename(config.Total2+filename, config.ID+MemberI+'.pdf')
        else: 
            print("Match not Found in DF2")
            # os.rename(config.Total+filename, config.ManualCheck+filename+'.pdf')
            matches1 = df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(Name) & df['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)]

            if len(matches1) == 1:
                row_index = matches1.iloc[0]['ID']
                print("Match Found in DF1")
                print(row_index)

                # MemberID = df.loc[row_index, 'ID']
                MemberI = str(row_index)

                os.rename(config.Total2+filename, config.ID+MemberI+'.pdf')
            else:
                print("Match not Found in DF1")
                # print("No Match Found in DF1, Search Df2")
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do here? Why not use something like `len(df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(name) & df['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(zip)]) == 1` to check for unique matches?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for; how could I implement this into my code? It seems to be the answer!

Comment: @ifly6 I have updated the question with your input. Now it's just failing with the renaming via error.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I added it above; when I print that as a variable, it's just printing 'True' or 'False' I still need the row number.. @ifly6

Comment: `df2['ID'][rowMatched2]` should probably be `df2.loc[row_index, 'ID']` to select the location (`loc`) in the dataframe at the `row_index` and the variable `'ID'`.

Comment: Undefined variable: 'row_index'Python(undefined-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your error:

```
UniqueMatch = len(df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(Name) & df['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)]) == 1
if UniqueMatch: # When rows match of NameUp and Zip var in DF1
    rowMatched = UniqueMatch
```

`UniqueMatch` is a boolean.

Consider instead:

```
matches = df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(Name) & df['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)]
if len(matches) == 1:
    row_index = matches.iloc[0].name
```

Getting the first (and here, only) entry's name yields the index of the row which you seem to be wanting. Perhaps it would also be even easier to just query what you want from the matches:

```
matches.iloc[0]['ID']
# get the first element, then the contents of the ID column
```

On your last comment, I renamed your variable from `rowMatched` to `row_index`, which is more consistent with Python conventions.

Comment: Thanks.. this is stating:    if len(UniqueMatch2) == 1:
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()

Comment: Of course; a boolean doesn't have a length; tt is either true or false. There is no length involved. Look at your declaration of `UniqueMatch2`, which assigns it as a boolean. Consider passing the subset instead of the boolean result of testing whether the length of that subset is 1.

Comment: I am using UniqueMatch where you are using 'matches'. Your matches is also a boolean?

Comment: No, my matches is a DataFrame containing the result of the query.

Comment: Gotchya! Now how can I get the value of a column via that row index gathered?

Comment: Yes you can! It’s in the answer!

Comment: I have updated the question one more time, with the most recent attempt; this seems to work for another round of matches, but then stops catching them just as my original code did. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check string case